# PHP compiler/interpreter

Tags: php, compiler

How to install PHP Compiler/Interpreter on ubuntu 11.04

I have latest version of PHP, but I want to learn PHP from terminal. Is there a PHP interpreter available that will run PHP programs inside terminal.

e.g. I want to run command like "phpc" or "phpi" or "php" to open up PHP REPL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just run

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

To run it in interactive mode:

```
php -a
```

Run a file:

```
php /path/to/file
```

Comment: and how to run the compiler/interpreter ? using command php ?

Comment: When I try that first command, I get a message:

"E: Package 'php5-cli' has no installation candidate"

Answer (score 3):

Run the interpreter (there's no compiler in default PHP) using the "php" command, yes. If you'd like to know where "php" comes from (what executable is launched), type

```
which php
```

This is likely to give you "/usr/bin/php" as an answer, unless you have a special setup.